# Difference between Superuser and supergroup in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, superuser

What is `supergroup` and `superuser` in Hadoop/HDFS?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for [sf] than a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Superuser**

Based on the [Hadoop official documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_permissions_guide.html):

> The super-user is the user with the same identity as the name node process itself. Loosely, if you started the name node, then you are the super-user. The super-user can do anything in that permissions checks never fail for the super-user.

**Supergroup**

Supergroup is the group of superusers. This group is used to ensure that the Hadoop Client has superuser access. It can be configured using `dfs.permissions.superusergroup` property in the `core-site.xml` file.

---

**References**

- [Hadoop superuser and supergroup](http://doc.isilon.com/ECS/3.2/DataAccessGuide/ecs_c_hdfs_users_superuser_supergroup.html)